# Capture IBM i Db2 SQL "Alternative file names"

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

I would like to capture all the "Alternative file names"  (SQL table name), as opposed to the the short 10 character IBM i "SYSTEM" name for a specific IBM i library. I can see the value using the DSPFD command, but can't seem to capture it in an DSPFD to OUTFILE.  Is there a command to do this, or an API?

```
 DSPFD FILE(MYSQL_LIB/*ALL) TYPE(*BASATR) OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) OUTFILE(QTEMP/TEMP)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all this information from SQL using qsys2.systables. Please see these links [IBM link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/milligan/0108milligan.html) and [RPG blog link](https://www.rpgpgm.com/2015/12/almost-everything-you-wanted-to-know.html)

EDIT: I have never used this but there is also this QUSLMBR [API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/apis/quslmbr.htm). I have always done this using systables.

Here's an example:

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM qsys2.systables
WHERE system_table_name = 'MYTABLE'
  AND table_schema = 'MYLIB'
```

The table name and schema must be in upper case.

Comment: for future reference, try to include the gist of the link, or in this case example code in your answer in case the link goes bad.